# Un mètre quatre-vingts pour 1,80 m

Tags: expressions, nombres

Pourquoi dit-on « un mètre quatre-vingts » quand on parle de 1,80 m ?

De la même manière, « quatre mètres douze » indique une longueur de 4,12 m, quand on pourrait entendre 4,012 m.

Comment: "*Un mètre quatre-vingt*" est beaucoup plus court et simple à dire que "*Un virgule quatre-vingt mètres*" :) Pareil pour "*Un euro cinquante*" vs "*Un virgule cinquante euros*" (qui en plus sonne comme "*cinquante euros*")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pour éviter des erreurs, s'il n'y a qu'un zéro, il est courant d'exprimer ce zéro entre la virgule et les premiers chiffres qui suivent, ce qui donne :

```
4,025m = quatre mètres zéro vingt-cinq
```

Ce zéro peut être répété si désiré :

```
4,003m = quatre mètres zéro zéro trois
```

Answer (score 2):

Dans les situations courantes, hors des contextes de mesure scientifique, il va sans dire que les chiffres qui suivent mètre représentent des centimètres.  Si on veut faire comprendre qu'on parle de 4,012 m, il faut dire :

- Quatre mètres et douze millimètres

ou, si on veut exprimer le tout en mètre,

- Quatre virgule zéro douze mètres

Comment: ou bien 4012 mm.